# How do I import classes from one project's testpackages to another project's testpackages in netbeans?

Tags: testing, netbeans, import, classpath, package

In netbeans I can setup several classpaths for a project: compile, processor, run, compile tests, run tests.

In compile tests I added another project. I can now use that other project's src packaged classes, in my own project's test packages.

But I can't use that other project's test packaged classes.

How can I make this happen?

(Do I need to use maven projects instead of regular projects?)

Comment: I am not a Netbeans user, so I cannot answer the question with regard to that IDE. I use IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse, usually in combination with Maven. Both of them can easily import and update changes from Maven builds, thus there is no need to maintain or even commit (uaaaah!) IDE project data. I assume Netbeans can also import Maven projects. If you know Maven and are ready to use it, I can help you. Otherwise I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some solutions for this problem [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51544). Suppose that you have a project `B` using the test classes of project `A`.

You can include `{project A}/build/test/classes/` in the test compilation
classpath for project `B`.

An other option is to automatically create JAR file from the test classes of project `A` with this code in `build.xml`:

```
<target name="jar-tests" depends="compile-test">
    <jar jarfile="testdist/tests.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.classes.dir}"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Then you can add the JAR to the test compilation
classpath for project `B`.

The test compilation process can be extended with test JAR generation with this code inserted into `build.xml`:

```
<target name="-post-compile-test">
    <jar jarfile="testdist/tests.jar">
        <fileset dir="${build.test.classes.dir}"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

It updates the `tests.jar` every time you compile (or run) the tests.

Answer (score -2):

In the Projects window you can expand the project that you are working on. Right Click on **Libraries** and select **Add Project**.... You will get a dialog allowing you to select another Netbeans Project with the Java classes that you wish to use.

OR

When you build the java project in netbeans it creates a jar file on the dist folder in the current project directory. You can use this jar file for the other project as a package by adding this as ADD jar in the next project.

Comment: this does not work at all for the problem i described.

Comment: then I didn't understand your question, sorry for that.